# How to change the sender's email address for messages sent on behalf of a Google Calendar API service account

Tags: google-api

I am using a Service Account to access the Google Calendar API.  My program creates calendars and shares them with users.  Currently, the users receive an email (sent by Google, not me) with a very long and awkward sender and a difficult to read message.

The sender looks like `3928472398472-ehrufh3478fh3487fh387fh32f7h2d323d@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

The message looks like this:

`We are writing to let you know that 3928472398472-ehrufh3478fh3487fh387fh32f7h2d323d@developer.gserviceaccount.com has given you access to edit events on the Google Calendar called "NewCal".`

Is there any way to specify the sender email address for these automatically generated emails, so that I can specify a name that my users will recognize and trust?  As it looks now, it is easy to assume that these are spam messages and they are ignored as a result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: same question. Did you figure it out?

Comment: It's been 8 years. Has anyone figured this one yet?